# How to include an exported package's version when using the OSGi plugin for Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, osgi, manifest, bnd

I'm trying to include the versions with the exported packages in the jar manifest being created by my Gradle project (using the OSGi plugin).  According to [this page](http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/170-versioning.html) I can do this either by including a packageinfo file with the version number

```
version 3.2.1-SNAPSHOT.${build}
```

or else I can use a `Version` annotation in the package-info.java file

```
@Version("3.2.1-SNAPSHOT.${build}")
package com.companyname;

import aQute.bnd.annotation.Version;
```

with a compile dependency in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile "biz.aQute.bnd:bndlib:2.1.0"
}
```

Unfortunately neither approach is working - the jar's MANIFEST.MF file isn't listing a version for the `com.companyname` package

```
Built-JDK: 1.8.0_71
Tool: Bnd-3.2.0.201605172007
Export-Package: com.companyname;uses:="com.companyname.config"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try using `org.osgi.annotation.versioning.Version`. The version annotation from the `aQute.bnd.annotation` package is obsolete.

Comment: Sadly the Gradle OSGi plugin has some deficiencies I ended up rolling my own OSGi plugin... Annoying but something to consider.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Thanks, that fixed the problem